# JS Marko (raptor templates) load dynamic template path in browser

Tags: javascript, browserify, marko

I am trying to use Marko templates in a web application, and would prefer to be able to load pre-compiled templates dynamically. My (weak) understanding is that the suggested raptor-optimizer does static analysis to load all of the templates (as does browserify), and so wouldn't be able to bundle templates only referenced dynamically.

Is it possible to do this without having to hard code every possible template path that I might be interested in? Is it possible to not have to surrender the concat and minify steps to raptor-optimizer/browserify?

```
first_tmpl = require('marko').load(require.resolve('./tmpl/first.marko'))
second_tmpl = require('marko').load(require.resolve('./tmpl/second.marko'))
```

https://github.com/raptorjs3/marko#browser-side-rendering

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Out of the box, Browserify only supports static code analysis for discovering and bundling dependencies. The RaptorJS Optimizer supports both static code analysis and declarative dependencies inside `optimizer.json` files. The RaptorJS Optimizer also supports glob patterns so that you can do the following inside an `optimizer.json` file:

```
{
    "dependencies": [
        "**/*.marko"
    ]
}
```

In most cases it is better to rely on discovering required templates via static code analysis.

I hope that helps.

--Patrick